# Can I use 16GB DDR3-1600MHz RAM in an early Macbook Pro 8.2?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, macos

I found Macs which had:

- 16GB RAM installed
- [8GB RAM installed, but running on 1600MHz](http://www.onemorething.nl/community/topic/1600mhz-pc3-12800-geheugen-in-macbook-pro-15-i7-2011-kingston-hyperx) instead of 1333MHz (link in dutch)

  [image]

### Question

Is it possible to put 16GB running at 1600MHz in my Mac?

If you've done this, please post a screen shot.

Apparently you need a Macbook Pro with an i7 processor of at least 2.2GHz or more in order to use memory running at 1600MHz.

### My hardware

- Macbook Pro 8,2  early 2011 - 2.0GHz i7 quad

**edit:**
I recently found this [sleepimage](http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/11/sleepimage-mac/). Basically it's just a swap file of your RAM. so your mac can 'sleep'. But when you install 16GB you're gonna have a 16GB RAM file sitting on your disk as well. Which you can safely delete but it will be recreated when your mac goes to sleep. just something to consider when your working with limited disk space.

Comment: I don't know why you accepted the answer provided. It's wrong. Users here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1133642 have upgraded their MBPs to 1600MHZ RAM without problems. Moreover, system profiler reports that it's rubbing at full speed.

Comment: Because it is not posible with the processor I have

Comment: sszemer, do you have the problem with the kernel_task process consuming a lot of RAM memory once you installed the 1600 modules ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to use RAM running at 1600MHz in *your* [Macbook Pro 8.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_2), because it's not supported by the processor.

Your Macbook Pro has the [Intel® Core™ i7-2635QM Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/53463/Intel-Core-i7-2635QM-Processor-(6M-Cache-2_00-GHz)) which **only allows DDR3-RAM running at 1066/1333MHz** according to Intel. (see link for official specs)

While the 2635QM processor does not support 1600MHz memory, it **does support 16GB RAM**:

[image: official specs from intel]

Comment: What about the screen-shot added to the question - I found it myself: it's the [i7-2720QM](http://ark.intel.com/products/50067/Intel-Core-i7-2720QM-Processor-(6M-Cache-2_20-GHz)), which supports: `Memory Types: DDR3-1066/1333/1600`

Comment: @iolsmit The screenshot if for the 2635QM.

Answer (score 3):

16 GB should be possible - but I'm quite sure it will always run at 1333 MHz, as the firmware sets the clock speed. Thus, even if you buy a 1600 MHz module it should run at 1333 MHz (**edit**: 1600 MHz is possible, see comments)

And I could not find any 8 GB module at 1600 MHz.

So I would recommend to get 16 GB at (at least) 1333 MHz.

[image: about this mac]

[image: memory]

Comment: I did find some screenshots with people having 8GB of mem running @ 1600mhz. I'll post the screen in my question.

Comment: the KHX1600C9S3P1K2/8G mem modules will run on 1600mhz but be aware the 8GX version will still run on 1333mhz according to the dutch article in my question

Comment: Good to know that Apple allows faster clock-speeds if the hardware supports it. But the [KHX1600C9S3P1K2/8G](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?ktcpartno=KHX1600C9S3P1K2/8G) is still a kit of two 4 GB modules - did you find a single 8 GB module at 1600 MHz ?

Comment: **How can we be sure that the 1600MHz are being used to the full potential?** Trying to get an answer here: [Using memory with a higher MHz rating?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73701/using-memory-with-a-higher-mhz-rating)

Answer (score 3):

I successfully bought and installed a 16GB Patriot kit (2x8GB) of PC3-1600 (12800) in my 15" MBP 8,2 (2.3Ghz Early 2011). Used to have 2x4GB PC3-1333, now it runs 2x8GB at 1600 speeds! No extra software needed, and even Boot Camp (Win 7) had no issues... so far. 48 hours since I installed it, and I feel good. While I know YMMV, just make sure you have HIGHER than 2.0 Ghz (2.2 and up) CPU and 2011 or newer, and you should be ok.  No idea about the 13" models, though.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I'm running the Early 2011 MBP with the 2.0Ghz intel core i7 2635qm (or 2630qm not sure) which by intel does not support 1600Mhz memory. 
Believe it or not; I've got 16gb ram buzzing at 1600mhz. My about this mac reports I can have two bars of 1600mhz and extended system information reports that my RAM is running at 1600mhz.

And by the way, 1333mhz and 1600mhz doesn't differ a lot in price now so why not take the chance. I can assure you it will work at 1600Mhz anyways.

Comment: At the time of asking this question there was bit of price difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have  a Late 2011 13" MacBook Pro 2.4 GHz i5. Bought a PNY PC3-12800 16GB (2x8GB) at 1600MHz for an upgrade. System profiler sees the full 16GB and at full speed of 1600 MHz. The box says the kit is backwards compatible to 1333 and 1066 MHz DDR3 speeds anyhow. So I recommend buying the PNY kit as it worked great for me and so long as it works according to the package it should down clock to be compatible if it doesn't run the full 1600 MHz. So either way you'll get your capacity upgrade but this way you might get lucky and receive a small speed boost too. Best of luck to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Check your computer make and model on [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com). It'll give you all the valuable intel you'll need to make the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed 16gigs 1600mhz ram in a 2011 17 inch MacBook pro i7 2.2 and it's working great and is running at 1600mhz in the system report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 1600Mz on 2011 17 MacPro that originally came with 1333Mz

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i also upgraded to 16GB 1600MHZ on my early 2011 i7-2720QM MBP. runs all good :)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed a 1600 MHz 16 GB RAM on my Late 2011 17 Inch MacBook and its running blazingly fast now. The Apple store denied me the request saying its un-supported for you Macbook and were also charging me almost double the price of the usual upgrade.

I ended up by adding Two Kingston 8 GB modules in my Macbook and it worked just fine.

For people in India they can get it from Amazon

http://www.amazon.in/Kingston-RAM-LAPTOP-1600MHZ-PC3L/dp/B00CQ35HBQ/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1456807582&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Kingston+8+GB+RAM+FOR+LAPTOP+1600MHZ+PC3L+-+KVR16LS118+macbook

Answer (score 0):

I took my Mac in for a service in 2015, it went in with Crucial Ram 1333Mhz and has come back with 1600 MHz RAM. They had to change the logic board so I think they accidentally changed the ram also.

It's interesting to see that replaced it with "Unsupported" RAM.

Yes, I think your Mac should run with 1600 MHz RAM as well.

Answer (score -1):

Im late also but the latter part of my post might assist someone to. My Late 2011, 15.4AntiGlare 2.2Ghz MBP,is running 16G of Corsair Vengeance- 1600Mhz, for 9 months now. Coincidently Apple just(in Dec) replaced my Logicboard+GPU under the extension program for certain models. **I did find out the OEM Factory Toshiba256G SSD only runs at 3G,Max its capable of. Kind of a Ripoff Apple on an SSD?!!?  Both Bays support 6G sata in my v8.2

.(Which I achieved a Sandisk240G Uktra6G/ Sale price $60. Along with a 1Tb Seagate SSHD running 6G in the optical bay).