# Can I add 16 gigs to the 13 inch non-Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

The latest updates to MBPs non-retina say they can support upto 8 gigs of RAM. I had a mid-2011 13 inch MBP which I upgraded to 16 gigs.

The 13 inch MBP has 2 RAM slots. Has anyone successfully added 16 gigs to this version MBP? Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question may also be helpful http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73701/using-memory-with-a-higher-mhz-rating

Answer (score 1):

[This article from the MacObserver says yes.](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/owc_announces_16gb_ram_upgrades_for_new_macbook_pro/?utm_source=macobserver&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=rss_everything)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article references by @Matthieu, I ordered 2 8gig RAM sticks from Other World Computer and have successfully installed 16 gigs of RAM on my 2012 MacBook Pro. The System Info panel does display 2 slots as containing 8 gigs each for a total of 16 gigs.

If you are ordering RAM please ensure that the voltage spec matches the newer model's 1.35V instead of 1.5V from the previous (2011) version. I do have 2 sticks of PC 133 DDR3 but the voltage requirement is 1.5. This could cause issues like some users have reported.