# How to down-clock RAM?

Tags: upgrade, memory

My Mac (**Mid 2009- MacBookPro5,5**) **laptop** installing OS **10.8.2**.

Currently, it is using **2 x 1GB (1066 Mhz)**.

My friend gave me **2 x 2GB (1600 Mhz)** of his 2012 Mac.

**After installing 2 x 2GB (1600 Mhz)** on my Mac, it can <strike>not</strike> boot but can not start OS. This is the error that show on <strike>boot</strike> start up screen:

[image]

But it is **possible** to install **1x 1GB (1066) + 1x 2GB (1600)**. The system can **down-clock** it to **both 1066 Mhz**. But what i still have 1 x 1GB (1066) + 1x 2GB (1600) **left**!

[image: 3GB @ 1066 Mhz]

**My question is:** Any **better** solution than using 1x 1GB (1066) + 1x 2GB (1600)?

**More certainly, is there any way to install 2 x 1600 Mhz? (even down-clocking to 1066 is accepted).** (currently, 2x1600 Mhz can not startup OS).

Edit 1: 4 RAM are healthy.

Comment: Relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42101/can-i-use-16gb-ddr3-1600mhz-ram-in-an-early-macbook-pro-8-2/42104#42104

Comment: Yep. A faster ram is always capable to speed down to lower frequences ...

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: My question is: how to do it. I am very appreciate the answer about how to down-clock 2x1600 to 1066 on this system? Because currently, i can not start my system with 2x2GB.

Comment: It should do it automaticaly. It's not the ram it self who desides at which speed it runs.

Comment: I've posted an answer that is incorrect. But it should do it automatically, if not, it's problem with the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran in to a similar issue when trying to squeeze a little more life out of an old iMac. I could only get 800mhz DIMM's but the specs say it needs 667mhz. I can interchange 1x 667mhz DIMM with 1x800mhz DIMM but a single 800mhz DIMM or two 800mhz DIMMs result in a failure to boot.

My hunch was that the motherboard *thinks* it can run at 800mhz so doesn't downclock it to 667mhz unless there is a slow DIMM in one of the slots forcing it to.

I did some research, and discovered the timing information is set in the SPD data stored on an EEPROM on the DIMM. I booted an Ubuntu 16.10 liveUSB on the iMac, `apt-get install`ed `i2c-tools`, `modprobe`ed the `i2c-i801` module to enable the SMBus (which talks to the DIMM EEPROM) and read out the SPD of a working and a too-fast DIMM with `i2cget`. After a lot more research, I merged the timing information from the working DIMM in to the SPD of the too-fast (but larger) DIMM. `decode-dimms` can calculate the correct CRC. I then wrote the modified data back to the fast DIMM with `i2cset`.

I can now pair that down-clocked DIMM with an unmodified 800mhz DIMM, and the system correctly downclocks  the memory bus to 667mhz and boots.

FULL DISCLOSURE: After about a month the upgraded machine started hard-crashing and was replaced by a 2017 iMac ;)

Comment: Cool, I ended up going this route, and was able to get my DDR3-1333 operating at 1066. Of particular assistance was Wikipedia's table of SPD contents for DDR3 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect#DDR3_SDRAM).  I was in a similar situation with my `MacBook6,1` to the `MacBookPro5,5`, although with the `B00` boot ROM it at least ran hot rather than crashing at boot. Obviously this is not an approach for everyone, as there are no easy second chances if you don't get the settings and the checksum updated properly the first time.

Comment: Cool, now at least I know there was a solution to my problem. After a few years from my question, I bought a pair of 2x4GB RAM@1066 :) My mac is still usable until today for "light weighted" task, since it can not handle "simple" 1080p on Youtube :(