# RAM upgrade for a macbook pro late 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a macbook pro late 2011.

At this moment I am running the basic 2x 2GB 1333MHz rams ,but I want to upgrade.

Now,I have read on some forum that this macbook can run 1600MHz rams even though Apple sold it with 1333MHz rams.

Any ideas what's up with this?I am a bit confused at this point as I don't know what to buy.

Also, are Kingston memory sticks good?I had a kingston SSD a few months ago and it was just great ,but don't know about rams.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with 8GB or 16GB. I have 16GB in my late-2011 MBP 15 inch. As I recall they are Crucial 1333mhz. No problems, she runs fast and sweet.

Comment: good choice, I has the same model model and the same memory upgrade.
do you install fresh OS X 10? I think that it could be necessary for performance

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you want to upgrade the RAM on your machine from 4GB to 8GB.I had a similar case for my early 2011 MBP (I've not still not upgraded RAM on my machine).

**Upgrade from 4GB to 8GB RAM**

1. How to find the current installed memory and it's details

[image]

2. Navigate [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1270) to match exact details

You can match the exact RAM details that you want for upgrade and that is 204-Pin , 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM.

You can search for same specifics online or in nearby stores.

**Using 1600 MHz in Place of 1333 MHz**

This question has previously been answered on this forum itself and I take no credit in providing the link

1. [Can I run 1600 MHz instead of 1333 Mhz?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73701/using-memory-with-a-higher-mhz-rating)
2. [Using 1600 MHz RAM](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42101/can-i-use-16gb-ddr3-1600mhz-ram-in-an-early-macbook-pro-8-2)

**Using 16GB RAM in your MBP**

As discussed [here](http://www.cnet.com/news/add-16gb-ram-to-your-macbook-pro/), you can use 16 GB of RAM in your MBP. (Please leave a comment if you successfully do this as I will also be interested in that.)

Let us know if you successfully choose any one of these options or we can count on someone who has already done it and would like to answer this question.

Good Luck !!!

Comment: Well, the point is that a trustworthy source of mine showed me a mid or early 2011 (can't remember exactly right now) ,with 16Gigs of ram running at 1600MHz.Therefor, it's a certain thing that you CAN upgrade from 1333MHz to 1600MHz.

BUT!There is a big but here.If you do that, you get 1600MHz and CL11 ,while with 1333MHz you get CL9.

Me?Unless I will buy a mac mini and sell this macbook, I will upgrade to 1333MHz rams.Why?Simply because the CL7 is more important to me than the 1600MHz which come with CL11.